# Neat way to calculate about: group by inside group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have some data of purchases records. Would like to see: group by `merchant`, what's the average number of different products **per customer**?

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLE purchases (
    id int IDENTITY,
    merchant varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    customer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    product VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    amount money
);

INSERT INTO purchases (merchant, customer, product, amount) 
VALUES 
    ('apple', 'John', 'iphone', 100),
    ('apple', 'John', 'macbook', 100),
    ('apple', 'Jessi', 'iphone', 100),
    ('microsoft', 'John', 'surface laptop', 100),
    ('microsoft', 'John', 'surface book', 100),
    ('microsoft', 'Jessi', 'surface book', 100)

-- I can do it with two layers of group by
select merchant
    , avg(cast(ct_product as float)) as avg_number_products_per_customer
from (
    select merchant
        , customer
        , count(distinct product) as ct_product
    from purchases
    group by merchant, customer
) as a
group by merchant
```

I can do it with two layers of `group by` as above, but ideally I want only one main `group by` so the code looks neat and also I can put other `sum`/`avg` together, eg:

```
select merchant
    , count(distinct customer) as count_customers
    , avg (amount) as avg_amount
    , ??? as avg_number_products_per_customer
from purchases
group by merchant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is really the best approach.  I would write it as:

```
select merchant, avg(ct_product * 1.0) as avg_number_products_per_customer
from (select merchant, customer,
            count(distinct product) as ct_product
      from purchases
      group by merchant, customer
     ) mc
group by merchant;
```

You could also do the calculation as:

```
select merchant,
       count(distinct concat(customer, ':', product)) / count(distinct customer)
from purchases
group by merchant;
```

Comment: the second way is what i was looking for! It's much neater to not use two layers of `group by` (see update in OP). Thank you! @Gordon Linoff